# How to get Created By and Last Modified Date using V2 Box iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, box-api

On fetching folder items using a folderID, i'm just getting only 5 items in the json response dictionary.

`{
    etag = 4;
    id = 924199771;
    name = Philips;
    "sequence_id" = 4;
    type = folder;
}`

I need Created By and Last Modified TimeStamp along with this response. I'm using Box V2 iOS SDK. Need help on getting this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify which fields you want like this:

```
BoxFoldersResourceManager *mgr = [BoxSDK sharedSDK].foldersManager;
BoxFoldersRequestBuilder *bldr = [[BoxFoldersRequestBuilder alloc] initWithQueryStringParameters:@{ @"fields" : @"name,type,id,size,modified_at,created_by" }];
[mgr folderItemsWithID:_folderId requestBuilder:bldr success:^(BoxCollection *collection) {
    // process results
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSDictionary *JSONDictionary) {
    // process error
}];
```

Be sure to list whichever fields you need when creating the `BoxFoldersRequestBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the fields paramater and separate the items you want returned by comma, Box's response will return created_by and modifed_at. You can also retrieve modifed_by.

http://developers.box.com/docs/#fields

?fields=created_by,modified_at